# Построение окружности на растре

Tags: ассемблер

Имеется задача. Она заключается в нахождении точек, ближайших к истинной окружности, т.е. в минимизации ошибки. Есть алгоритм, который рисует 1/8 окружности:

```
INC X ;наращиваем X  
ADD DX, X ;увеличиваем d на величину X  
CMP DX, Y ;сравниваем с Y  
JL Paint ;если меньше, то вывод точки  
SUB DX, Y ;иначе уменьшаем d на Y  
DEC Y ;и уменьшаем Y на 1  
JMP Paint
```

(Paint - рисование точки с координатами x, y)

Вопрос: как реализовать алгоритм рисования окружности на основе алгоритма данной дуги?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это алгоритм Брезенхейма для окружностей.
Ваша часть алгоритма описывает дугу, для которой происходит наращивание X и уменьшение Y при движении по дуге окружности по часовой стрелке. Т.е. это часть окружности, которая начинается в точке (0,1).
Полное описание [здесь](http://algolist.manual.ru/graphics/painting/circle.php).

Answer (score 2):

Здесь можно воспользоваться симметрией. Так, применив симметрию (поменяв местами х и у), получаем рисование 1/4 окружности (снизу-справа). Теперь остальные дуги мы можем реализовать с помощью изменения знака координат (+/-) относительно центра окружности :)
Простой пример выглядит так (это видеоадаптер CGA, цветной, где 1 байт = 4 пикселя, а также 1ая половина памяти содержит данные только о нечетных линиях экрана, а 2ая половина - о четных, подробнее [здесь](http://www.frolov-lib.ru/books/bsp/v03/ch4_2.htm)):

```
.model  small
.data
bitmask db 64, 16, 4, 1  
parts db 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 ; номера дуг, которые требуется отобразить
x1               equ      50       ; координаты левого верхнего угла
y1               equ      50    
radius           equ      30    
y           dw       0
x           dw       0
d           dw     0
part                dw       0
.code
mov     ax, @data
mov     ds, ax
mov     ax, 04h         
int     10h             
mov     ax, 0B800h          ; загрузка адреса начала
mov     es, ax      ; видеопамяти в регистр ES
mov ax, radius
mov y, ax
Arc:
; ----- Это ваш алгоритм рисования 1/8
mov     dx, d
INC X               ; наращиваем X
ADD DX, X               ; увеличиваем d на величину X
CMP DX, Y               ; сравниваем с Y
JL  Paint               ; если меньше, то вывод точки
SUB DX, Y               ; иначе уменьшаем d на Y
DEC Y               ; и уменьшаем Y на 1
JMP   Paint
Paint:
; ----- рисование точки
mov     d, dx
mov     si, part
mov     cl, parts+[si]          ; записываем номер дуги в cl
cmp     cl, 0             ; не отображаем дугу, если = 0
je      NextStep
mov     bx, x                     ; определяем знак x координаты
cmp     cl, 5             ; если номер дуги <5, то "+"
jl      PositiveX             ; иначе - "-"     
neg     bx
PositiveX:
add     bx, x1    
mov     ax, y                    ; определяем знак y координаты 
cmp     cl, 3            ; если номер дуги <3 или >=7, то "+"
jl      PositiveY            ; иначе - "-"
cmp     cl, 7
jnl     PositiveY
neg     ax
PositiveY:
add     ax, y1       
and     cl, 01h         ; если номер дуги четный
cmp     cl, 0           ; то пользуемся свойством симметрии
jne     WithoutChange       ; (меняем координаты местами)
mov     dx, ax
mov     ax, bx
mov     bx, dx
WithoutChange:  
mov     dx, bx         
and     dx, 03h         ; выделяем 2 последних бита
mov     cl, 2          
shr     bx, cl  ; делим x на 4, тк в байте 4 пикселя, по 2 бита на пиксель
mov     cx, ax
and     cx, 01h        
cmp     cx, 0                   ; определем чётное или нечётное 
jz  EX
add     bx, 2000h
EX: 
mov     cl, 1
shr     ax, cl          ; ax = (y-1)/2 or y/2 - т.к. банк только четных/нечетных строк
mov     cl, 4
sal     ax, cl          ; ax = (y/2)*16, bx=x/4
add     bx, ax
mov     cl, 2
sal     ax, cl          ; ax = (y/2)*64, bx =x/4 + (y/2)*16
add     bx, ax          ; bx = x/4+(y/2)*80 - полных байт
xor     ax, ax
mov     si, dx
mov     cl, es:[bx]     ; считываем текущую маску
mov     al, bitmask+[si]        ; в al - маска 
or      al, cl
mov     es:[bx], ax
NextStep:  
; ----- переход к следующей итерации либо завершение рисования   
mov     ax, y
cmp     ax, x
jnl     Arc         ; продолжаем рисовать ту же дугу
mov     ax, radius      ; переход к следующей дуге
mov     y, ax           ; очистка переменных
mov     x, -1
mov     d, 0
inc     part
cmp     part, 8
jne     NextStep
xor ax,ax   
int 16h
mov ax,4c00h    
int 21h
end
```